# How to retrieve Json post data

Tags: php, json, api, curl, slim

I have made an API using SLIM in php. I am calling the API using curl by passing some post parameters. I have passed multiple parameters and when I print them out in gives  me this:

```
"name=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Ftest%2FAPI%2F1jpg&cwt=1&fwt=1&swt=1&twt=1&dwt=1&slwt=1"
```

The multiple variables are seperated by '&' how can I get the 'name' variable the 'cwt' variable seperately??

My code calling the API is:

```
$url='http://......./API/index.php/search';
$data=array ("name"=>"/var/www/test/API/1jpg","cwt"=>"1","fwt"=>"1","swt"=>"1","twt"=>"1","dwt"=>"1","slwt"=>"1");
$response=sendPostData($url,$data);
function sendPostData($url,$post){
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($post));
curl_exec($ch);
```

My API:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app=new \Slim\Slim();
    $app->post('/search',function () use($app){
    $result=($app->request()->getBody());
    $final=json_encode($result);
    echo $final;

});
$app->run();
```

How can I print the name,cwt,twt and all the variables seperately?

Answer (score 2):

Look for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

It should be:

```
$string = urldecode("name=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Ftest%2FAPI%2F1jpg&cwt=1&fwt=1&swt=1&twt=1&dwt=1&slwt=1");
$vars   = array();
parse_str($string, $vars);

print_r($vars);
```

It will give you this:

```
Array ( [name] => /var/www/test/API/1jpg [cwt] => 1 [fwt] => 1 [swt] => 1 [twt] => 1 [dwt] => 1 [slwt] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in a string is to split the string like this

```
$pizza  = "piece1&piece2&piece3&piece4&piece5&piece6";
$pieces = explode("&", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Then you could split them again with the "=" sign to separate the keys from the values and recombine them into a Multidimentiional array

I use this as my approach

Then use the array keys for cwt value in your case [Multidimentional Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and for the functions [Array Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)